# Schoolchildren population or schoolchild population?

Tags: adjectives, grammatical-number, word-usage, modifiers

Although we are taught to use singular adjectives to modify nouns, "schoolchildren" population seems to be a more commonly heard and searched (Google) option than the true singular "schoolchild" population. Is popular usage defeating correct grammar?

Comment: student population

Comment: "Citation required", I think. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=schoolchild+population%2Cschoolchildren+population%2Cstudent+population%2Cpupil+population&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) (for British English, at least)

Comment: Population of schoolchildren.

Comment: Where is the town of Schoolchildren? Neither of the two phrases is idiomatic, and *population* begs for some explicit geographical reference - *Denver's population of school-aged children.*

Comment: The citation requested:
These findings are in agreement with the association between socioeconomic variables and the overall prevalence of dental caries observed in both this sample and that of other schoolchildren populations from Brazil.